# how can i join the two arrays from controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controller

How can I join the two arrays from controller? I tried to use `AND` operator as shown below but I failed. How can I make it possible?

```
function view_product($category_id)
{
    $category_id=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('select');
    $this->data["products"]=$this->select->get_products($category_id);
    $this->data["prices"]=$this->select->get_price($category_id);
    $this->load->view("header");
    $this->load->view("products",
    $this->data);
}
```

here is my view:

```
<?php
$n=0;
foreach(($products as $product) && ($prices as $price) ) {
    $n++;
    echo '<tr><td>' .$n .'</td><td>'.$product['product_id'].'</a></td>
          <td>'.$product['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$product['product_description'].'</td><td>'.$price['price_per_unit'].'</td><td>'.$price['price_per_item'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';        
?>
```

My model

```
function get_products($category_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('categories c');
    $this->db->join('products p', 'c.category_id=p.category_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('c.category_status = 0');
    $this->db->where('c.category_id', $category_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

function get_price($category_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('categories c');
    $this->db->join('price r', 'c.category_id=r.category_id', 'c.product_id=r.product_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('c.category_status = 0');
    $this->db->where('c.category_id', $category_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

How can i join the two arrays from controller?

Comment: Please post the data structure for both arrays

Comment: Why would you need to? I notice that in the view you are accessing `$price` but in the controller you are naming the variable 'price's with the line `$this->data["prices"]=$this->select->get_price($category_id);`

Answer (score 0):

to iterate over 2 arrays, use `array_map`

```
function output_prices($product,$price) {
    $n++;
    echo '<tr><td>' .$n .'</td><td>'.$product['product_id'].'</a></td>
    <td>'.$product['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$product['product_description'].'</td><td>'.$price['price_per_unit'].'</td><td>'.$price['price_per_item'].'</td></tr>';
}
array_map('output_prices',$products,$prices);
```

source:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

Please change your View as per below mentioned code.

```
<?php
$n=0;
$merg_detls=array_merge($products,$prices);
foreach($merg_detls as $detl) {
    $n++;
    echo '<tr><td>' .$n .'</td><td>'.$detl['product_id'].'</a></td>
          <td>'.$detl['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$detl['product_description'].'</td><td>'.$detl['price_per_unit'].'</td><td>'.$detl['price_per_item'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';        
?>
```